# Vertical UIStackView alignment

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a vertical UIStackview with 3 controls in it.
I want all the controls to be centered, and the first two to expand the whole width available. The third one should take 80% of the available width and be centered as well.

Here is the result I got so far:

[image]

As you can see the third control is left aligned.

Here is the code I have for all of this:

```
    var container = new UIStackView
    {
        TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
        Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical,
        Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualCentering,
        Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Fill,
        Spacing = 10f
    };
    // Create the Title
    UILabel title = new UILabel
    {
        TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
        Text = item.name,
        TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
        Lines = 2,
    };
    
    container.AddArrangedSubview(title);
    
    // Create the gauge
    SFCircularGauge circularGauge = new SFCircularGauge { TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false };
    circularGauge.Tag = circularGauge.GenerateViewTag();
    circularGauge.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(100f).Active = true;
#if DEBUG
    circularGauge.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan;
#endif    
    container.AddArrangedSubview(circularGauge);
    
    // Add the evaluate button
    var evaluate = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
    evaluate.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    
    evaluate.SetTitle(Utilities.GetLocalizedString("qol_rate_button_text"), UIControlState.Normal);
    evaluate.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
    evaluate.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(red: 1.00f, green: 0.37f, blue: 0.00f, alpha: 1.0f); // Optimistic Orange
    evaluate.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;
    evaluate.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
    evaluate.ContentEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10f, bottom: 0, right: 10f);
    
    evaluate.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    
    evaluate.TouchUpInside -= Evaluate_TouchUpInside;
    evaluate.TouchUpInside += Evaluate_TouchUpInside;
    
    evaluate.Tag = evaluate.GenerateViewTag();
    viewIdsAutoEvalsIds.Add((int)evaluate.Tag, item.id);
    
    container.AddArrangedSubview(evaluate);
    
    evaluate.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(container.WidthAnchor, 0.8f).Active = true;
    evaluate.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(container.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;
```

I can't figure out where is my problem. In the UIStackView configuration? Somewhere else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bug of the control. We'll [see](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents/286582).

In the meantime, thanks again to the Reveal Tool, the gauge has no width defined.

I solved the problem by setting the width constraint explicitly:

```
// Fix the width to be 100% of the container     
circularGauge.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(container.WidthAnchor).Active = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The property **Alignment** is to sets the alignment of the non-axial subviews . In your case , you need to set it as

```
UIStackViewAlignment.Center
```

instead of

```
UIStackViewAlignment.Fill
```

Comment: This solved the problem for the button, but introduced a new one for the 2nd control (gauge) that is no more visible.

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Comment: The SFCircularGauge is a [SyncFusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin-ios/Syncfusion.SfGauge.iOS~Syncfusion.SfGauge.iOS.SFCircularGauge.html) control that you could freely download and try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217872/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-olivier-matrot).